# Want to run 8080 port existing server block which has SSL running on 80?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl-certificate, https, port

I am already running my site on 80 and want to open another port says 8080 but its not working when I typed "https://papa.fit:8080".

***server block* papa.fit**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name papa.fit www.papa.fit;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;



    root /var/www/waev.in;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name papa.fit www.papa.fit;
        include snippets/ssl-papa.fit.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

#set client body size to 2M#
#       client max body size 2M;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }


}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;

    server_name papa.fit www.papa.fit;

    root /var/www/laravel_api/public/demo/;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: you use https when you query it, but you configured the server to serve http, not https.

Comment: So Where should I change @GeraldSchneider

Comment: If I want to run 8080 on https

Comment: compare your block to the existing ssl block. The difference is easy to spot.

Comment: Should I create another server block like "papa.fit:8080" and then add all this settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `ssl` directive, as well as the certificate configuration.

Change

```
listen 8080;
listen [::]:8080;
```

to

```
listen 8080 ssl;
listen [::]:8080 ssl;
```

And add this inside the block:

```
include snippets/ssl-papa.fit.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
```

You didn't include these files in your post, so we don't know what's in it, but let's assume it is only the certificate configuration. In this case it should be enough.

Comment: I added this files but got "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" in browser.

Comment: yes. that include is all about ssl certification.

Comment: Do you get any useful information in the nginx error log?

Comment: yes this is "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 180.148.40.7, server: 0.0.0.0:8080"

Comment: With the given information it's not possible to help you further. Please edit actual error messages from both the client and the server logs into your question. "It doesn't work" is not a helpful error description.

Comment: If you have SSL configured on the server block, you need to use `https://` to access the site. If you don't have SSL configured, then you need to use `http://` to access the site. The error message looks like a mismatch between these two.